# Cocos2d ColorLayer makes half of the screen go black

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I have a standard scene with the `init` method as follows:

```
@interface CommodoreScene : CCLayerColor

@end


@implementation CommodoreScene

- (id) init {
    if (( self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)] )) {

    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

However when I run the scene on my iPhone4, or the simulator half the screen goes black, the other half my layer color (white).

I'm currently running the scene with `[_director pushScene:[CommodoreScene node]];` and running cocos2d-iphone 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id) init {
    if (( self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) width:480 height:320] )) {

    }

return self;
}
```

Try that. The important part is of course the change in the call to super. You might still have an issue with [[CCDirector] winSize] reading properly in the -init method if you're in landscape (which judging from the bug you're experiencing - you are), at least I did on my tests. As I recall, this is a known bug of some kind, as it seems to read the winSize as portrait instead of landscape. You can fix this by doing the following:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
CGSize size = rect.size;
// position the label on the center of the screen
label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
```

Using that newly created size instead of winSize in your -init method fixes the issue. Notice that if you create and position an element *after* initialization, such as in onEnter, this problem goes away and the winSize from the director reads properly. Odd bug, it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can change content size of your color layer;

```
CGSize boxSize = CGSizeMake(sGame.winWidth, sGame.winHeight);
CCLayerColor *box = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(155,155,200,255)];
box.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
box.contentSize = boxSize;

[self addChild:box z:-6];
```

Comment: I'll try it out... strange, as this has never really happened to me before when I've used `CCColorLayer`.

Comment: Hmmm... the same thing is happening! I'll look into it more, it's very strange.